# Portable Class Library not compatible targets, but should be

Tags: xamarin, nuget, autofac, nuget-package, portable-class-library

I am trying to create a Portable Class Library which uses Autofac, but I am getting an installation error. I run

```
Install-Package Autofac
```

Which results in the following:

[image]

Here are the targets of my Portable Class Library.

[image]

When I look at the Autofac package downloaded through the nuget for other projects, it looks like it should support my PCL.

[image]

I have even downloaded the source for Autofac and here are the targets for the Autofac project.

[image]

So, why am I seeing the error? This is not specific to Autofac either. I get similar errors with other frameworks such as Portable.Ninject. I have tried creating PCLs with various permutations of targets and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will need to be rebuilt against the new Unified API, which is Xamarin.iOS10 in that message: http://blog.xamarin.com/how-to-update-nuget-packages-for-64-bit/

Comment: Thank you. The key was the "[Visual Studio 2013 Extension 2.8.50926.663 or above.](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4ec1526c-4a8c-4a84-b702-b21a8f5293ca)" download.